# KEDA delay between event scale down and actual scal down

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I noticed a delay between when i provoke a scale down and when the pod actualy start teminating it used to be like 40 seconds now it takes 5 minutes
i saw some suggest to configure ***--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-cpu-initialization-period*** but I am using k8s with docker desktop I think that I can't change k8s configuration

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: spring-consumer
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: consumer-deployment
  triggers:
    - type: rabbitmq
      metadata:
        queueName: projqueue
        host: *****
        mode: QueueLength
        value: "5"
  minReplicaCount: 1
  maxReplicaCount: 5
```